# UK visitor visa reconsidering after Pap how long new decision will take?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-rejections

I have applied for a UK visitor visa on 24th May 2021 and received a refusal on 1st June and I sent ECO a Pre-action protocol letter and he sent me reconsidering letter on 7th June. How long the new decision will take as it was clearly ECO’s mistake that he didn’t read my documents with the application. Will they interview me and I didn’t receive my passport even after 10 days of refusal decision?
Please come up with answers
[image][image][image]

Comment: Please add an image to your question (using the "edit" link below your question text, and then the "moon and mountains" button in the composition window) of the entire refusal letter you received, after obscuring your name and address and other personal information contained in the letter.

Comment: I attached refusal letter received on 01 June and then reconsidering letter received on07 June.It was ECO mistake that he understood I m receiving money from My cricket club that’s not true

Comment: @Chiku attach both the refusal letters.

Comment: First one was my mistake I didn’t show evidence of funds it’s nothing to do with 2nd refusal, 2nd refusal can be overturned they mentioned in pap about reconsidering so 2nd does matter

Comment: The images are too small. When enlarged, the text becomes blurry and remains unreadable. Please delete these images, and attach readable ones.

Comment: The attached docs are now readable, but they show one refusal, dated June 10, 2021, not two. The sequence of events is not clear. As @Aak requested, please attach both refusal letters so we can understand what happened. It's important that the docs are attached within your question, so that everyone here can read them.

Comment: I have attached 1st refusal also

Comment: And in 2nd refusal 10th June is not the Refusal date it’s PAP letter response on 10th June

Comment: Have I understood correctly? You’ve applied twice (what were the dates?) and had two refusals. In one application you say you want to visit for nearly 6 months and will fund the trip from your own/your mother’s resources, in another you plan to visit for 3 months to play cricket and will receive £4000 from a UK cricket club, which UKVI has understandably deemed a payment. What’s your connection with the club, why are they paying you? Why have you changed the basis of the application from self-financed to paid? Why do you want to visit in the middle of a pandemic? Please edit your question

Comment: Whatever comes out of reading the refusal letters, we can not predict how long a decision will take.

Comment: @Willeke Agreed. Normally there is an expected standard of 14 days for an initial response, but Covid may have affected that. If the initial response upholds the refusal decision and the OP decides to go for the full judicial review, I suspect a decision could take months. On the face of it the OP probably needs advice from an immigration lawyer on the validity/likelihood of success and possibly with help to prepare the case for judicial review, in which case the lawyer ought to be able to indicate a decision timeframe. https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/what-is-a-pre-action-protocol-letter/

Comment: @traveller I think you misunderstood My first Refusal main reason is I didn’t show my financial ties with my employment.After first refusal my visit was only 3 months cause cricket season is ongoing and half season has done I will play for the club that’s why they will spend money on my trip Flights, accommodation rather giving me cash in hand that’s where ECO made mistake.In 2nd application I showed them my income of proof too.And i haven’t gone for JR yet as ECO thinks he made a mistake and will review application.

Comment: When first time I apply it was on 9th April and received decision on 21st April. And 2nd time I applied on 24th May and Received decision on 1st June.And I sent them Pap letter on 3rd June and received response on 10th June.It says they will contact me but haven’t done yet

Comment: I am professional cricketer been to some countries before to play cricket and my performance helped me to get contract from Club in Uk.Where they are responsible for all my expenses in return I will play for them.And my Traveling dates are from July so I guess travel ban will be lift as cases are dropping in India or another option I can stay for 10 days in an Amber list country to Travel in Uk this cricket season is so important for my career so I intend to travel

Comment: @Chiku In the UK, “cash in hand” is a well-known euphemism for being paid under the radar. Since you are a professional cricketer I don’t think the activities you intend to do in the UK are allowed as a visitor https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/938632/visit-guidance-v10.0ext.pdf#page34 You state you have a contract with the UK cricket club, IMHO you need a T5 work visa https://www.gov.uk/temporary-worker-creative-and-sporting-visa

Comment: No but isn’t type of contract which pay money.There is clearly a category in visitor visa taking part in Sport activities and many of my playmates gone Uk on same Visa every year even my contract letter says that the club doesn’t pay to any player and I attached that to my application